# What does "f***ing pay" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, offensive-language

I have never seen "fucking pay" before. what does it mean. I have read this in this sentences " Let's hope you're right. that's all I have to say. Because otherwise... you know? soneone, somewhere is going to fucking pay."

Comment: The phrase "someone is going to pay" means, essentially, "I am going to physically harm someone as punishment for the fact that I was inconvenienced in this issue."  It's an extremely common phrase in - say - gangster or crime movies in the US.  (The swear word is just an an intensifying adverb, as tChrist explains.)

Answer (score 4):

The OED lists 55 terms with *fuck* in them.  It is an extremely versatile and productive word, occurring variously as an interjection, noun, adjective, participial adjective, verb, adverb, and deverbal noun. As a non-native speaker just learning English, I highly recommend that you learn all 55 of them, because you will encounter them again and again. :)

Here in your example sentence, *fucking* is used as an **adverb** and, in particular, as a simple **adverbial intensifier** like *really*, but with a negative and coarse connotation like *bloody, bleeding,* or freaking*.

This particular use the OED explains under its *fuck* head-word <sup>(not to be confused with a *fuck-head word*)</sup>:

> Hence **ˈfucking** *vbl. sb.* Also as *ppl. a.* and *adv.*, used esp. as a mere intensive.
>
> - **A. 1568** A. Scott *Poems* iv. 55 ― Thir foure, the suth to sane, Enforsis thame to fucking.
> - **1680** Rochester *Poems on Several Occasions* (1950) 30 ― Through all the Town, the common Fucking Post, On whom each Whore, relieves her tingling Cunt.
> - **1707** [see **frigging** *vbl. sb.*].
> - **C. 1888–94** *My Secret Life* III. 228 ― This house had but eight rooms, and two mere closets to let out for fucking.
> - **C. 1888–94** *My Secret Life* VIII. 307 ― She was··a magnificent bit of fucking flesh, but nothing more.
> - **1893** Farmer & Henley *Slang* III. 80/2 ― *Fucking*··Adj., A qualification of extreme contumely. Adv. Intensitive and expletive; a more violent form of *bloody*.
> - **1922** Joyce *Ulysses* 580 ― I’ll wring the neck of any bugger says a word against my fucking king.
> - **1929** F. Manning *Middle Parts of Fortune* I. ii. 23 ― Blown to fuckin’ bits as soon as we got out of the trench, poor bugger.
> - **1930** J. Dos Passos *42nd Parallel* 94 ― It was a fucking shame it was Freddy hit you.
> - **1938** Dylan Thomas *Let.* 31 Aug. (1966) 208 ― None using obscene words, none··to do with fucking.
> - **1939** Dylan Thomas *Let.* 29 Sept. (1966) 240 ― I’ll give Dent the whole fucking works.
> - **1960** D. Lessing *In Pursuit of English* 12 ― ‘What the f‑‑ing hell’s that for?’ my father said.
> - **1969** Auden *City without Walls* 49 ― I’m so bored with the whole fucking crowd of you I could scream!
> - **1971** *It* 2–16 June 18/3 ― The Youngbloods··are so fucking good they can do spontaneous albums.

Compare this with its sense for *bloody*, first for the adjectival one:

> **A 10 a.** In foul language, a vague epithet expressing anger, resentment, detestation; but often a mere intensive, esp. with a negative, as ‘not a bloody one’. Prob. from the adv. use in its later phase.

And then for the adverbial one:

> **B.** *adv.* **2.** As an intensive: Very....and no mistake, exceedingly; abominably, desperately. In general colloquial use from the Restoration to *c* 1750; ‘now constantly in the mouths of the lowest classes, but by respectable people considered ‘a horrid word’, on a par with obscene or profane language, and usually printed in the newspapers (in police reports, etc.) “b‑‑y”’. *N.E.D.* **Also in tmesis.**
>
> > <sub>[The origin is not quite certain; but there is good reason to think that it was at first a reference to the habits of the ‘bloods’ or aristocratic rowdies of the end of the 17th and beginning of the 18th c. The phrase ‘bloody drunk’ was apparently = ‘as drunk as a blood’ (cf. ‘as drunk as a lord’); thence it was extended to kindred expressions, and at length to others; probably, in later times, its associations with bloodshed and murder (cf. a bloody battle, a bloody butcher) have recommended it to the rough classes as a word that appeals to their imagination. We may compare the prevalent craving for impressive or graphic intensives, seen in the use of *jolly*, *awfully*, *terribly*, *devilish*, *deuced*, *damned*, *ripping*, *rattling*, *thumping*, *stunning*, *thundering*, etc. There is no ground for the notion that ‘bloody’, offensive as from associations it now is to ears polite, contains any profane allusion or has connexion with the oath ‘’s blood!’]</sub>

As noted at the end about also being in tmesis is relevant to *fucking* as well. Intensifying profanity is often used for expletive infixation; that is, it is used tmetically.

- bloody unbelievable ≣ unbloodybelievable
- fucking unbelievable ≣ unfuckingbelievable  (or less often, unbefuckinglievable)
- fricking unbelievable ≣ unfrickingbelieveable (or less often, unbefrickinglievable)

Comment: Guys, the question is about the use of "pay" in this sense.  (As you pointed out "f-ing" is just an intensifying adverb.)

Answer (score 0):

In that context, "fucking" is simply an interjection.  The sentence is "someone, somewhere is going to pay."  "Fucking" is there for emphasis.

Comment: A similar example- _"I'm gonna make sure as hell he pays"_.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. It is not an interjection. It as an intensifying adverb. An interjection would be like *“Fuсk! Now what am I going to do?”*

Comment: My question is about " f---ing pay" not just one part.

Comment: Vocabulary isn't everything.  The point is that the phrase is 'going to pay', not just '<intensifier> pay'.